# Single column ListView in Portrait but Two columns in Landscape?

Tags: android, listview

I'm making a list that display Phone Contact. It works but does not looks good in Landscape orientation since it just stretched out.

So I decided to make it *two column while in Landscape* and *one column in Portrait*. I can't seem to find any reference by googling.

Is there any way to do it? It would be great if I just need to put custom XML in `layout-land` folder

Thanks

[UPDATE]

In Portrait it will be like this:

```
name 1
name 2
name 3
name 4
```

In Landscape:

```
name 1    name 2
name 3    name 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into `Fragment`s http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html

Basically you will have two layout folders for this, just like you suggested.

- res/layout/main.xml (use for portiat)
- res/layout-land/main.xml (use for landscape)

You'll build your interface into `Fragment`s and place two of them in the landscape and one in portrait. For example

```
public class ContactListFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_list, container, false);
        // do your work
        return view;
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // configure your fragments here.
    }
}
```

**res\layout\main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ContactListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/contact_list_fragment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**res\layout-land\main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ContactListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/contact_list_fragment1"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.android.fragments.ContactListFragment"
              android:id="@+id/contact_list_fragment2"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Wow, I never know we can do this, great. But what I want is two columns of contact name side by side while in Landscape. Is it possible? I update the question, so it won't cause confusion, Sorry

Comment: You'll want to use the same `ContactListFragment` twice in this case and just display what you want in each. I'll update the example

Comment: Does it have to extends `FragmentActivity`? Because the class already extends `ListActivity`. I tried without `FragmentActivity` and it gives me `InflateException`: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Change `ListActivity` to `ListFragment`. You'll have a few things to change around

Comment: It does display two ListViews side by side. But only the right side get filled with the contacts, even though both has same `id`. How to reference the other ListView?

Comment: I've never used two fragments of the same fragmemts on the same screen, but guessing it populates the first one it finds with the same id. You will need to reference each as separate ids I'd suspect.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used a GridView. Depending on the orientation change the numColumns field to 1 or 2.